# jGrowl - like plugin using qTip 2.0 (jQuery). Positioning problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, position, qtip, qtip2

Okay, I am trying to simulate the jGrowl notification plugin using qTip. qTip have a demo of how such a feature can be made:

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#growl

However, this positions the notifications in the top right corner, I want them in the bottom right corner. I have tried to mess around with the positioning, and it's good up to a point, I just can't get the updating position effect to work properly. If there are at least 3 notifications on the page, when one disappears, the second repositions perfectly, the others don't.

Can someone please help me get the `updatePos` function to work as expected?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bCcAB/

Answer (score 1):

In Create function instead of

```
my: target.length ? 'bottom center' : 'bottom right',
at: target.length ? 'top center' : 'bottom right',
```

type

```
my: 'bottom right',
at: target.length ? 'top right' : 'bottom right',
```

In Update function instead of

```
api.options.position.target = !i ? [$(window).width() - 5,$(window).height()] : [
                    pos.left + width,
                    pos.top - height - 5
                ];
api.set('position.at', !i ? 'bottom right' : 'top center');
api.set('position.my', !i ? 'bottom right' : 'bottom center');
```

type

```
api.options.position.target = !i ? [$(window).width() - 5,$(window).height()] : [
                    pos.left + width,
                    pos.top
                ];
api.set('position.at', !i ? 'bottom right' : 'top right');
```

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/bCcAB/1/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just change the style of the container?
The original code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/YCfx4/
so just change

```
#qtip-growl-container{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px; right: 10px;
}
```

to

```
#qtip-growl-container{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px; right: 10px;
}
```